# Queue of Thread objects

Tags: java, multithreading, list, linked-list, queue

I am trying to have some Threads on a Queue so I can manage them from there. Is this possible? I have some code but it don't work correctly.

The main idea is to generate X threads and put every thread inside a queue in another class. Then in the class who have the queue use wait() and notify() methods to have a FIFO execution order.

Thanks in advance.

Some of the code:

```
public synchronized void semWait(Thread petitionerThread){

    count--;

    if(count < 0){

        try {
            petitionerThread.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        FIFOQueue.add(petitionerThread);    
    }
}

public synchronized void semSignal(Thread noticeThread){

    count++;

    if(count <= 0)
        if(!FIFOQueue.isEmpty())
            FIFOQueue.pollLast().notify();
}
```

Edit: The problem is that when a Thread enters the queue and it is put to wait, something happen that the semSignal method is never executed for any of the other threads (its called after semWait()).

Comment: There's nothing fundamentally wrong with this approach.  If it's not working, there's probably a bug in your code.  Could you please post the code here so that we can look over it and offer useful feedback?

Comment: why are you not using the executor framework of java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html

Comment: @templatetypedef I have edited and added some of the code. I am not sure if I am doing it right...

Comment: @vishal_aim I didn't know about it. I am checking it out, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check BlockingQueue(concrete class LinkedBlockingQueue) in java. This queue allows you to put any object into it, for that matter even Thread. The queue.put() will wait if the queue is full. And queue.get() will wait if queue is empty. wait() and notify() are implicitly taken care of. 
Then a set of threads can take from the queue and execute them in order. 
We are talking of a producer-consumer problem.

Comment: Yeah, I have heard about this class. Right now I am trying to figure it out what I am doing wrong, but with my queue. But thanks, I will considerate using this to solve my problem.

Actually I do have some restrictions, this because is a course project.

Answer (score 0):

Your code violates one basic programming rule: let object governs itself. First, code that waits/notifies should be inside the methods of that object. Then, if you want a thread to behave some way, program its run method accordingly. In the code, you try to manipulate threads as if they are ordinary objects, while they are not. Low-level code which treats thread as objects is implemented already in wait/notify/synchronized and whatever synchronization primitives, and you need not to reimplement the wheel, unless you make a new operating system.

Looks like you are trying to implement Semaphore. In this case, your methods need not parameters. `semWait` should place in the queue current thread, and `semSignal` release a thread from the queue and not the thread passed as argument.

One possible implementation is as follows:

```
class Sem {
  int count;

  public synchronized void semWait() throws InterruptedException {
    while (count <= 0) {
      wait();
    }
    count--;
  }

  public synchronized void semSignal() {
    count++;
    notify();
  }
}
```